# jquery find previous based on class name

Tags: jquery, find

I'm trying to use jquery to find an item based on it's class name. Basically I have this structure:

```
<ul class="vm_cat">
    <li><a class="mainlevel" href="/">MAIN LEVEL 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="sublevel" href="/">sub 1 a</a></li>
    <li><a class="sublevel" href="/">sub 1 b</a></li>
    <li><a class="sublevel" href="/">sub 1 c</a></li>
    <li><a class="sublevel" href="/">sub 1 d</a></li>
    <li><a class="mainlevel" href="">MAIN LEVEL 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="sublevel" href="/">sub 2 a</a></li>
    <li><a class="sublevel" href="/" id="active">sub 2 b</a></li>
    <li><a class="sublevel" href="/">sub 2 c</a></li>
    <li><a class="mainlevel" href="/">MAIN LEVEL 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="sublevel" href="/">sub 3 a</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want jQuery to find which a tag has an id of "active", then to find the previous a tag with "mainlevel". So it would find "sub 2 b" and then find "MAIN LEVEL 2" as it is the previous a tag with a class of "mainlevel".. if this makes any sense??

I know this would be a lot easier if the list was structured correctly, but this is what I have to work with unfortunately. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), like this:

```
$("#active").parent().prevAll(":has(.mainlevel):first")​.children()
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/UG2gr/)

This goes up to the parent, then searches all previous siblings that contain the provided selector (using [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)), and they're in reverse order (nearest sibling first), so you want the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) one, then go to the child to get the `<a>` inside the `<li>`.

Comment: +1 - Yep, the `:has()` capped it off. Don't know what I was thinking! :o)

Comment: is there any way of hiding the sub level items, belonging to a mainlevel "group" which doesn't have an item with "active" as the id?

Comment: @SoulieBaby: Is there any reason for the main levels not being a `<li>` set of siblings, each with a `<ul>` underneath, containing `<li>` elements that are the `.sublevel` ones?  This would simplify everything greatly.

Comment: I'm trying to modify an already structured system, I don't have access to the specific files to re-do that list :S I can only modify certain pages *sigh*